# How to declare a type in typescript based on the keys mentioned in the same type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to declare a type in typescript ApiResponse and mention 3 keys in it which are isError, error, and content. What I want is that type should be declared as such that either isError and error exist or content exists.

```typescript
type ApiResponse<T> = {
    isError?: boolean;
    error?: ErrorContent;
    content: this.isError ? undefined : User; // this is something I want . how should I do it.
}
```

I want this so that when I call a function which wants a parameter of User type doesn't give an error that the parameter is undefined

Comment: What are you doing with `T` and what type is `ErrorContent`?  You could rewrite that type as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) but without a [mcve] I can test I'm not comfortable suggesting it.

Comment: For example, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/KN79oW) work for you?  If so, I'll write it up as an answer.  If not, please elaborate by modifying your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't define type based on dynamic value here,

1. one we need to use generic to get `User` type
2. Instead of isError boolean we should use `status` kind of enumeration (`success, error`)

so that we represent invalid state properly. Try like below,

```
type ErrorContent = {};
type User = {};

interface SuccessResponse<T> {
  status: "success";
  content: T; // this is something I want . how should I do it.
}

interface ErrorResponse {
  status: "error";
  error: ErrorContent;
}

type ApiResponse<T> = SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse;

const success: ApiResponse<User> = {
  status: "success",
  content: {}
};

const failure: ApiResponse<User> = {
  status: "error",
  error: {},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to define type differently by variable. Simply you can define the type using `|` operator.

```
type ApiResponse<T> = {
  isError?: boolean;
  error?: ErrorContent;
  content: User | undefined;
}
```